# Bridge distribution mechanism says "none" despite it having been set in torrc?

Tags: configuration, bridge, obfs4

So I am running a new bridge relay at https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#details/D8931228F0FEB5668C7F5680D9B6CDB2AF86690E

Oddity happening, despite it being listed in the torrc confoguration to be distributed by email,the relay information says 'Bridge distibution mechanism: None". But also, the bridge states it is getting traffic in the tor log.

Here is the torrc:

Nickname udeservefreedom
ExtORPort auto
ORPort 00000
BridgeRelay 1
PublishServerDescriptor 1
BridgeDistribution email
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\obfs4proxy.exe

Note that the port was excluded so as not to share that on here. Thank you. But I wonder why it still says no distribution mechanism despite that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Nickname udeservefreedom
ExtORPort auto
ORPort 00000
BridgeRelay 1
PublishServerDescriptor 1
BridgeDistribution email
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\obfs4proxy.exe
```

Shoudn't be there an additional port for the obfs4?
Something like:

ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:*portnumber*